# strtotime function not working properly

Tags: php

I'm trying to print only the weekdays with the format of Y-m-d using this code

```
$strtdate = "2017-04-10";

$incrmntvar = 0;

while($incrmntvar <= $gettotaldays){
    $checkday = date("D",strtotime($strtdate));

echo "{$checkday} and {$strtdate}". "<br>";
    if($checkday != 'Sat' || $checkday != 'Sun'){

        $incre_date = strtotime("1 day", strtotime($strtdate));
        $strtdate = date("Y-m-d", $incre_date);     
        $incrmntvar ++;


    }

    else{
        $incre_date = strtotime("1 day", strtotime($strtdate));
        $strtdate = date("Y-m-d", $incre_date);
        echo "else " . $strtdate . "<br>";

    }


}
```

but it prints all the days including the saturday and sunday. What's wrong with my code

Comment: `$checkday != 'Sat' && $checkday != 'Sun'` Hope you guess why.

Comment: Or use an array: `if (!in_array($checkday, ['Sat', 'Sun'])) {`

Answer (score 1):

In your Sat/Sun day comparison, you're using or (`||`), instead of and (`&&`). If `$checkday` is `'Sat'`, then the check of `$checkday != 'Sun'` will still return true, and thus it will still output the weekend days.

Thus, the following line

```
if($checkday != 'Sat' || $checkday != 'Sun')
```

Should be corrected to

```
if($checkday != 'Sat' && $checkday != 'Sun')
```

Comment: You meant and instead of or  :)

Comment: @DaveS How so? He is using or instead of and as far as I can tell? :)

Comment: Thanks @TimeSheep for turning my quick response into a proper answer.

Comment: d'oh!  need more coffee, read it backwards, several times in a row.  sigh.